# How to integrate Hibernate Validator into Tomcat 7?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I've successfully integrated JSF (Mojarra) and CDI (Weld), but can't get Hibernate Validator to work.

The following jars are added to WEB-INF/lib:

```
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
classmate-1.0.0.jar
```

Tomcat 7 comes with EL 2.2 jars so I didn't add them.

My JSF page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText id="hello" value="Hello, #{testController.name}!"/></h1>
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{testController.name}"/>
            <h:message id="error" for="name"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Change Name">
                <f:ajax execute="name" render="hello error"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And my backing bean:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestController {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 5)
    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        name = "Bill";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

It's expected that when the size of the name is smaller than 3 or bigger than 5, an error message is shown, but it turns out to be not. Seems the Hibernate Validator is not working . I did see it's detected but was no longer logged:

```
Mar 11, 2014 9:31:40 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.0.Final
```

Is there anything wrong?

**Update**

Finally I figured out it's a Mojarra regression. The Hibernate Validator works now with MyFaces.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the Validator instance and invoke it?

Comment: I expect the validation should happen automatically, just like what it does in GlassFish.

Comment: I see. I have always invoked it manually in Tomcat, but I'm curious to know if it's possible to do that automatically. Hopefully someone else will know.

Comment: Please post the answer as an Answer not as an update to the Question. This way you can mark it accepted and it will be clear to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just to avoid confusion (as I have been confused, looking for the error despite it had already been solved because I didn't see the update section at the end of the post), let me add the answer on behalf of the OP:

It seems the OP used a Mojarra version that was broken. They solved the problem by migrating to MyFaces (see the update to their question). FWIW, I tried their example using Mojarra 2.2.12, and it worked fine.

Comment: OT being 'original topic'? And with which version did it fail?

Comment: @Kukeltje Oops - it seems OP (original poster) and OT (original topic) is often confused in German forums :). I fixed this. As for your question: Being in a hurry, I missed the update section which contains the solution. After pondering a couple of minutes about my mistake, I decided to add an answer myself, hoping to help other hurried developers avoid this trap.

Answer (score -1):

When you say you integrated with Tomcat 7, how did you do that? There is some glue code in application servers which make sure that for example the ValidatorFactory is visible to JSF. Not sure whether something like this would be required for you as well.

Have you enabled debug/trace logging to verify whether Validator bootstraps or get called?

Also you could try to add  to the JSF page, but this should be optional.

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you missing the `<f:validateBean>` tag on the page? I think you might also need to call the `Validator.validate(bean)` method in order to get it to fire.

Comment: Provide an example of which modifications you are talking. Otherwise this answer will be more like a comment.

Comment: @Marged I suspect you were confused by the hidden `<f:validateBean>` tag :).

Comment: You don't need a `<f:validateBean>` tag to activate JSR303. It works out of the box. All you need is the EL API and implementation, the validation-api.jar and the hibernate-validator.jar - just like the OT did.